# argparse and unittest python

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` to handle command line arguments. The code was working fine. However, as soon as I am adding `unittest.main()` in the main, it is not working.

I am getting:

```
I am here 
option -i not recognized
Usage: testing.py [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs

Examples:
  testing.py                               - run default set of tests
  testing.py MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
  testing.py MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
  testing.py MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                               in MyTestCase
```

I am doing like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "I am here"
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: There is no option `-i` so the error would be correct. How do you call the script?

Comment: I am calling the script like: python testing.py -isVerbose True

Comment: Then that is one problem: you should call it as `python testing.py --verbose` because you have no option declared called `isVerbose`.

Comment: No. I have defined isVerbose. args = parser.parse_args()

isVerbose=args.isVerbose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
itersuite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestClass)
runner.run(itersuite)
```

instead of:

```
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works now. Have not understand why the unittest.main() was failing.

Comment: unittest.main() seems to a look at any args passed to the main code, so it was trying to resolve your custom args which, of course, it couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need any arguments, use

```
unittest.main(argv=[''])
```

Comment: Excellent addition!